# Javascript Guessing Game

Tags: javascript

I'm brand new to javascript and html so I was hoping someone could peek at my code and tell me why certain syntax isn't working. In the code below I use document.getElementById to retreive the element I'd like to work with each time. I do declare them as local variables within gameTime() and use it throughout the function.

```
    var randNum = Math.floor( 100*Math.random() ) +1;
    var numGuesses = 0;

    function gameTime()
    {   
        var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
        var status = document.getElementById("status"); 

        numGuesses++;

        if(guess == "")
        {
            alert("You did not guess a number!")
            numGuesses--;
        }
        else if(guess == randNum)
            status.value += (guess + " was the right number! It only took you " + numGuesses + " tries" + "\r")
        else if(guess > randNum)
            status.value += (guess + " is too high!" + "\r")
        else    
            status.value += (guess + " is too low!" + "\r")

        document.getElementById("guess").value = "";
    }

    function reset()
    {
        randNum = Math.floor( 100*Math.random() ) +1;
        numGuesses = 0;
        document.getElementById("guess").value = "";
        document.getElementById("status").value = "";
    }

    function quit()
    {
        document.getElementById("status").value += ("The correct number was " + randNum + "!\r")
    }
```

Then I tried it by globally declaring the two elements and use it in every function which does not seem to work at all and I just don't understand why.

```
    var randNum = Math.floor( 100*Math.random() ) +1;
    var numGuesses = 0;
    var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
    var status = document.getElementById("status");

    function gameTime()
    {   
        numGuesses++;

        if(guess == "")
        {
            alert("You did not guess a number!")
            numGuesses--;
        }
        else if(guess == randNum)
            status.value += (guess + " was the right number! It only took you " + numGuesses + " tries" + "\r")
        else if(guess > randNum)
            status.value += (guess + " is too high!" + "\r")
        else    
            status.value += (guess + " is too low!" + "\r")

        guess.value = "";
    }

    function reset()
    {
        randNum = Math.floor( 100*Math.random() ) +1;
        numGuesses = 0;
        guess.value = "";
        status.value = "";
    }

    function quit()
    {
        status.value += ("The correct number was " + randNum + "!\r")
    }
```

And here's the html file that accompanies these js files guess.js is the first code block, guessAgain.js is the second code block.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Guessing Game</title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="guessAgain.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <label for = "guess"> Your Guess: </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "guess" value = "" />    
            <input type = "button" onclick = "gameTime()" value = "Submit" />  
            <input type = "button" onclick = "reset()" value = "New Game" />
            <input type = "button" onclick = "quit()" value = "Quit" />
            <br>    
            <textarea id = "status" rows = "10" cols = "52"></textarea>  
        </body> 
    </html>
```

Thanks for any insight you can give me.

Comment: You could consider providing a http://jsfiddle.com so that people easily can try out the above code/program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**
You are calling the following before the body loads and hence, they return undefined.

```
var guess = document.getElementById("guess");
var status = document.getElementById("status");
```

You should do these only after the body loads on the `onload()` event.

**Issue 2:**

Also, when you assign the value itself to a variable, it isn't updated as the textbox is. `var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value`, then `guess`'s value does not get updated if you change the textbox.

If you refer to `var guess = document.getElementById("guess")`, then, repeatedly calling 
`guess.value` will return the latest value of the input field.

**[(Working Example)](http://jsfiddle.net/PZ6s6/)**

---

The following is not wrong by unnecessarily **complicated**.

```
        numGuesses++;   
        if(guess.value == "")
        {
            alert("You did not guess a number!")
            numGuesses--;
        }
        ...
```

Instead, you could increment numGuesses once it is deemed a valid guess, i.e. at the end.

Comment: With your help I got it figured out. I woke up this morning and thought about the assignment I gave var guess and var status and realized why it wasn't working. The onload() event also helped. Thanks again.

Comment: Cheers :) Mark the above as answer if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting guess to element.value

It should be

```
var guess = document.getElementById("guess");
```

Problem is that you're using `guess` as an element here:

```
guess.value = "";
```

You'll also need to modify places where you use `guess` as a string into `guess.value`.

Comment: if that is the case, then another modification is needed to take into consideration that 'guess' is no longer a value, but an element, so the if condition should be ' if (guess.value == "" )' and so on.